# HTML Full Screen Image Margin Issue

Tags: html, css

Okay, I know that the margin:0 style sheet makes sure there's no white background border around my full screen image that completely fits the screen without any border/margin around it. The problem is, I'm only able to apply this style sheet to the body tag. But then **all the text in my body tag gets shifted completely to the left along with the image, hiding a bit of the text.** Basically, I want the margin:0 style to apply only to the image and not the text. I tried all kinds of stuff like applying that tag to a div and putting the image inside a div...etc, but it wouldn't work. The margin property only seems to work for the body tag.

The owl image below is completely full screen and works fine, but some of the text below it gets shifted two the left (because the margin is now 0) and gets hidden.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body     
{
    margin:0; 
}
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
<img src="owl.jpg"> 
</div>

THIS TEXT GETS SHIFTED TO THE LEFT HIDING SOME OF IT
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

**Reference 1**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 .test
 {
     margin:0; 
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="test" id="test">
 <img src="owl.jpg">
 </div>
 The image now has a margin around it and is not completely full-screen. Same thing for   this text
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The text inherits the margin value from `body`. Simply create another CSS class `#text{ margin: 20px; }` or whatever margin you want for the text and wrap the text in that `<div id='text'>`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Like I said, so far the margine:0 style has only worked for the body tag for me. See **Reference #1**

Comment: What browser are you using? I've tried in latest FF and IE 9 and itlooks just fine. I've tried with 2 different large images and text is fully visible right under the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything right next to the edge of the window then you should set the margin to 0. However if you want the text shifted back then you can wrap that in a container and format that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>by the way title is mandatory</title>
        <style>
body { margin: 0; }
.text { padding-left: 10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="test"><img src="owl.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="text">
THIS TEXT GETS NOW SHIFTED FROM THE LEFT BY A LITTLE
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**edit**

Although I'd recommend adding a wrapper inside the body tag (helps structuring later) if you really want to do it without it you can use this styling:

```
body { margin: 10px; }
#test { margin-left: -10px; }
```

This will add a margin to the body, so everything will have a white 'border' around it except for the `#test` image

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to do it? The idea is that I only need the image to have no margin and everything else on the page (divs, paragraphs, text, all kinds of other stuff) to have a margin. Following this method,  i'll have to give a "test" class to everything else other than the image. Is there something like negative padding that I can give to just the image?

Comment: Thanks that helps. Before I saw your update, I tried the div position attributes and it turns out that can override the margin. So I can simply shift a divider more to the left and more to the top and increase the image size, and that'll make it completely full screen as well